# Adding Outside Stroke to NSString in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I am trying to add a stroke to a text and showing in `UITextView`.

Here is what I want.

In the picture (CREATED FROM PHOTOSHOP) there are same font used, first one has `Postion "OUTSIDE"` and bottom text has `position INSIDE`.

[image]

I am using following code in Objective-C

```
  NSShadow * shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

    NSDictionary * textAttributes =
    @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
       NSShadowAttributeName          : shadow,
       NSStrokeColorAttributeName     : [UIColor blackColor],
       NSStrokeWidthAttributeName     : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-3.0],
       NSFontAttributeName            : [UIFont fontWithName:@"UbuntuCondensed-Regular" size:40] };

    textTitleResult.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textTitle.text
                                                               attributes:textAttributes];
```

I am achieving INSIDE effect. How can I set position to OUTSIDE

Comment: Maybe with `NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:+3.0],`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a property that can do exactly when you want. However, I have an idea which will possibly provide you with a way to "fake" it.

You can add another label at the exact position of the original one. The new label would have half the size of the stroke but the stroke color would be the same color as the text. Since the stroke "sits" on the border (half part inside the text and half part outside), it would block half of the original stroke, making it look as if it's on the outside.

Without making the code too pretty, it would look something like this:

```
UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:infoLabel];

UILabel *secondInfoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoLabel.frame];
    secondInfoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:secondInfoLabel];

NSDictionary * secondTextAttributes =
@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
   NSStrokeColorAttributeName     : [UIColor whiteColor],
   NSStrokeWidthAttributeName     : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-3.0],
   NSFontAttributeName            : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:40] };

secondInfoLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Welcome To" attributes:secondTextAttributes];

NSShadow * shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2;

NSDictionary * textAttributes =
@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
   NSShadowAttributeName          : shadow,
   NSStrokeColorAttributeName     : [UIColor blackColor],
   NSStrokeWidthAttributeName     : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-6.0],
   NSFontAttributeName            : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:40] };

infoLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Welcome To" attributes:textAttributes];
```

Another option would be to create your own custom view and draw it yourself just the way you want it (in `drawRect`).